# How to solve require is not defined while using CDNs for babel and react?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am currently trying to integrate a React App into a PHP website as a backend. And I am using CDNs for Babel and React. I have read many tutorials about webpack, but they only come up with an HTML and to run on NPM server or something.

```
<script type="text/babel" src="react_apps/App.js"></script>
```

I have added the react-app using the script below. 
And it works perfectly fine without any imports but I want to have a cleaner look and need to join two files together to work. So I finally created two components and import it as I have learned to do it in create-react-app.

```
import MainDashBoard from './MainDashboard/MainDashboard'
import SideNav from './SideNav/SideNav'
function App(){
    return(
        <div>
            <MainDashBoard />
            <SideNav />
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("MainReact"))
```

However, I am getting the error "require is not defined" in the console log. Here is the console log: [Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDf6r.png)

Is there anyway to make this work or do I need to run two separate server? One for PHP and one for NPM? 
I am really new to npm.

Comment: Are you really going to need both php and Node.js?

Comment: I mean, I am using PHP as a backend and React as a frontend.